# How to make the textfield remember history of words typed in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Do we have an option to make the GXT textfield remember the history of the words that have been given as an input. So when i click the textfield next time, it should list all the searches below the textbox. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short, what I would do. After blur, persist the value to a list, this map may need to be persisted to local storage or a database. And then on key press, filter the values in the list, this list could be loaded into a store, so the filtering utilities can be used. Once you filter, you can use the textField.getElement().alignTo(...) to align a listview below the field with the items in the list filtered.

Comment: I am not able to achieve this. Can you please provide a piece of code for this ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an editable combobox. In order to look like text field and hide the arrow image in combobox, you can use setHideTrigger(false). So, you can have a combo box that functions like a text box. Also, you can add all the search terms in a store. That is it. You are done.